# RadGridView occasionally doesn't draw until I move the mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

I am having an occasional problem with a radGridView where items that I add to an observable collection are not shown in the grid until I mouse over where it should be. Most of the time it works fine, but It is happening enough that it needs to be addressed. Calling rebind doesn't make any difference.

What could be causing the grid to not update until the mouse is moved?

Comment: And what version of telerik? Also, not bad to see xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was a render problem. By adding the line `RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly` I solved the problem, though scrolling is much slower.